# Subclassing a Subclass of PFObject

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, subclassing

I have utilized subclassing of PFObject for a few classes in my code including the following classes:

`MGRound:PFObject` - a class that represents a golf round

`MGCurrentRound:MGRound` -  a singleton class that holds data for the current round being entered.  As you can see it is a subclass of MGRound

When I try to instantiate an object of class MGRound using `[MGRound object]` the object that I am getting is of the class MGCurrentRound.

Has anyone else run into this?  Any suggestions?

Comment: probably you are using the "self" inside static method object ( i suppose it is so ). Print the code implementation of "object" method

Answer (score 0):

The issue noted above was not my problem.  I had to use the valueForKey method because the objects were PFObjects, not my subclasses.  I was trying to use dot notation was which incorrect.